# gradle ignoring latest build

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

I have a **gradle based** (v2.4) project with these entries:

```
repositories {
      maven { url "http://artifacts.us:8081/artifactory/repo" }
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
}

...
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

...
(bunch of modules)

compile(group:"com.mystuff", name: "some_util", version: "+", changing: true)
}
```

In **artifactory** I have versions 0.0.1 - 0.0.7 (all *-SNAPSHOT*) of `some_util` available.

When I run a build (via **jenkins**) it keeps building with 0.0.6-SNAPSHOT despite the presence of the 0.0.7-SNAPSHOT build.

What I've tried:

- putting a build step (in jenkins) `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies clean`
- the above `changing: true`
- the `resolutionStrategy` entry

What am I overlooking? Is gradle v2.4 too old?

Comment: Does your build work if you put in `0.0.7-SNAPSHOT` explicitly?

Comment: Yes. If I paste in the recommended build line from **artifactory** it works.

Comment: Hmm.. how do you publish 0.0.7 to artifactory? I'm wondering if there is something wrong in the repo metadata? Could you run gradle with both `--refresh-dependencies` and `-i`. Gradle should log dependency download interactions, and post the relevant sections?

Comment: Is jenkins relevant to this question? Do you have the same problem if you run the build locally without jenkins?